# Printing a value using XSLT/Xpath

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I'm working on an XML document with XSLT, and I can't get this to work.

Here's my simple XSLT document. I've used the template from w3schools.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="/">
  <html>
  <body>
    <h1>VAT No.:</h1>
    <table border="1">
      <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
        <th>Prefix</th>
        <th>Number</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="/document/page/body/dd[1]/dd[1]/dd/table/cell[1]/para[1]/ln[1]/wd[3]" /></td>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="/document/page/body/dd[1]/dd[1]/dd/table/cell[1]/para[1]/ln[1]/wd[4]" /></td>
      </tr>
    </table> 
  </body>
  </html>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

As you can see, I'm only trying to display the two words given. I've only left it in the table format so that I change the origional code from w3schools as little as possible.

Instead of having the two words displayed in the table, I get this:

[image: What I get]

*Unless there's something silly I'm missing* the Xpaths are correct. I even used an online Xpath viewer to confirm it. 
I have tried various placements of /, * and //. As well as editing the line.

Here is a part of the input XML. It is incomplete since there is some sensitive information, but you can see the layout.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16"?>
<?xml-stylesheet href="XSLT Stylesheet.XSL" type="text/xsl"?>
<!--XML document generated using OCR technology from Nuance Communications, Inc.-->
<document xmlns="http://www.scansoft.com/omnipage/xml/ssdoc-schema3.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<page ocr-vers="OmniPageCSDK18" app-vers="OmniPage 19">
<description>
<source file="C:\Users\dan\Pictures\7740411202.jpg" dpix="300" dpiy="300" sizex="3375" sizey="2330"/>
<theoreticalPage size="Custom" marginLeft="134" marginTop="40" marginRight="45" marginBottom="1184" offsetY="-84" width="16200" height="11184"/>
<language>en</language>
</description>
<body>
<section l="14275" t="40" r="15715" b="228">
<column l="14275" t="40" r="15715" b="228">
<para l="14308" t="84" r="15697" b="197" alignment="left" spaceBefore="2" lsp="exactly" lspExact="174" language="en">
<tabs position="14308"/>
<ln l="14669" t="84" r="15631" b="197" baseLine="182">
<run underlined="none" subsuperscript="none" fontSize="800" fontFace="Times New Roman" fontFamily="roman" fontPitch="variable" spacing="0" foreColor="0c0c0c"><wd l="0" t="0" r="0" b="0">Page</wd>
<tab position="14669"/>
</run>
<run underlined="none" subsuperscript="none" fontSize="800" fontFace="Times New Roman" fontFamily="roman" fontPitch="variable" spacing="0" foreColor="0c0c0c"><wd l="15185" t="89" r="15218" b="194">1</wd>
<space/>
<wd l="15326" t="84" r="15470" b="197">of</wd>
<space/>
<wd l="15595" t="89" r="15631" b="194">1</wd>
</run>
</ln>
</para>
</column>
</section>
<dd l="139" t="266" r="8777" b="3762">
<dd l="4297" t="266" r="8777" b="1807" backColor="d3d3d2" bottomDistance="375">
<bottomBorder type="single" width="2" color="d7d7d7"/>
<dd l="4297" t="266" r="8777" b="1807">
<table l="4297" t="266" r="8777" b="1803" alignment="left">
<gridTable>
<gridCol>3899</gridCol>
<gridCol>581</gridCol>
<gridRow>1537</gridRow>
</gridTable>
<cell gridColFrom="0" gridColTill="0" gridRowFrom="0" gridRowTill="0" alignment="left" verticalAlignment="top">
<para l="4373" t="367" r="6322" b="679" alignment="left" li="72" spaceBefore="53" lsp="exactly" lspExact="197" language="en">
<ln l="4373" t="367" r="6322" b="482" baseLine="480" underlined="none" subsuperscript="none" fontSize="800" fontFace="Times New Roman" fontFamily="roman" fontPitch="variable" spacing="0" foreColor="0c0c0c" forcedEOF="true">
<wd l="4373" t="367" r="4572" b="480">HP</wd>
<space/>
<wd l="4618" t="367" r="4944" b="480">VAT</wd>
<space/>
<wd l="4985" t="370" r="5213" b="482">No:</wd>
<space/>
<wd l="5388" t="367" r="6322" b="480">GB31414xxx
</wd>
</ln>
<ln l="4373" t="562" r="5738" b="679" baseLine="677" underlined="none" subsuperscript="none" fontSize="800" fontFace="Times New Roman" fontFamily="roman" fontPitch="variable" spacing="0" foreColor="0c0c0c" forcedEOF="true">
<wd l="4373" t="562" r="5446" b="679">Hewlett-Packard</wd>
<space/>
<wd l="5491" t="562" r="5738" b="677">Ltd.</wd>
</ln>
</para>
<para l="4375" t="744" r="7368" b="1042" alignment="left" li="72" ri="828" lsp="exactly" lspExact="182" language="en">
<ln l="4375" t="744" r="7368" b="883" baseLine="859" underlined="none" subsuperscript="none" fontSize="800" fontFace="Times New Roman" fontFamily="roman" fontPitch="variable" spacing="-2" foreColor="0c0c0c">
<wd l="4375" t="744" r="4673" b="859">Cxxx</wd>
<space/>
<wd l="4718" t="744" r="5083" b="883">Rxxx,</wd>
<space/>
<wd l="5134" t="749" r="5522" b="862">Axxxx</wd>
<space/>
<wd l="5566" t="746" r="6007" b="859">Cxxxxx</wd>
<space/>
<wd l="6055" t="746" r="6701" b="883">Bracknell,</wd>
<space/>
<wd l="6754" t="744" r="7368" b="859">Berkshire</wd>
<space/>
</ln>
<ln l="4375" t="929" r="5100" b="1042" baseLine="1042" underlined="none" subsuperscript="none" fontSize="800" fontFace="Times New Roman" fontFamily="roman" fontPitch="variable" spacing="-2" foreColor="0c0c0c">
<wd l="4375" t="929" r="4747" b="1042">Rxxx</wd>
<space/>
<wd l="4812" t="929" r="5100" b="1042">1xx</wd>
</ln>
</para>
<para l="4375" t="1169" r="5590" b="1282" alignment="left" li="72" spaceBefore="61" lsp="exactly" lspExact="179" language="en">
<ln l="4375" t="1169" r="5590" b="1282" baseLine="1282" underlined="none" subsuperscript="none" fontSize="800" fontFace="Times New Roman" fontFamily="roman" fontPitch="variable" spacing="0" foreColor="0c0c0c">
<wd l="4375" t="1169" r="4901" b="1282">GREAT</wd>
<space/>
<wd l="4949" t="1171" r="5590" b="1282">BRITAIN</wd>
</ln>
</para>
<para l="4375" t="1406" r="6528" b="1550" alignment="left" li="72" spaceBefore="61" spaceAfter="242" lsp="exactly" lspExact="179" language="en">
<ln l="4375" t="1406" r="6528" b="1550" baseLine="1522" underlined="none" subsuperscript="none" fontSize="800" fontFace="Times New Roman" fontFamily="roman" fontPitch="variable" spacing="0" foreColor="0c0c0c">
<wd l="4375" t="1406" r="4766" b="1522">Phone</wd>
<space/>
<wd l="4810" t="1406" r="5366" b="1522">Number:</wd>
<space/>
<wd l="5395" t="1411" r="5597" b="1550">(44</wd>
<space/>
<wd l="5664" t="1409" r="6007" b="1550">1xxx)</wd>
<space/>
<wd l="6062" t="1409" r="6528" b="1522">36xxxxx</wd>
</ln>
</para>
</cell>
<cell gridColFrom="1" gridColTill="1" gridRowFrom="0" gridRowTill="0" alignment="centered" verticalAlignment="top">
<picture l="8196" t="305" r="8738" b="1769" alignment="centered" ri="39" spaceBefore="39" spaceAfter="34">
</picture>
</cell>
</table>
</dd>
</dd>
<dd l="4297" t="2182" r="8777" b="3762">
<para l="6444" t="2215" r="8683" b="2345" alignment="justified" li="2088" lsp="exactly" lspExact="207" language="en">
<ln l="6444" t="2215" r="8683" b="2345" baseLine="2342">
<run bold="true" underlined="none" subsuperscript="none" fontSize="900" fontFace="Times New Roman" fontFamily="roman" fontPitch="variable" spacing="7" foreColor="0c0c0c"><wd l="6444" t="2218" r="7390" b="2345">DELIVERY</wd>
<space/>
</run>
<run bold="true" underlined="none" subsuperscript="none" fontSize="800" fontFace="Times New Roman" fontFamily="roman" fontPitch="variable" spacing="7" foreColor="0c0c0c"><wd l="7447" t="2220" r="7692" b="2342">TO</wd>
<space/>
<wd l="7795" t="2220" r="8683" b="2342">0000610727</wd>
</run>
</ln>
</para>
<para l="6449" t="2496" r="7646" b="2628" alignment="justified" li="2088" spaceBefore="84" lsp="exactly" lspExact="195" language="en">
<ln l="6449" t="2496" r="7646" b="2628" baseLine="2626">
<run bold="true" underlined="none" subsuperscript="none" fontSize="800" fontFace="Times New Roman" fontFamily="roman" fontPitch="variable" spacing="2" foreColor="0c0c0c"><wd l="6449" t="2496" r="7034" b="2628">Cxxxxx</wd>
<space/>
<wd l="7082" t="2503" r="7246" b="2626">IT</wd>
<space/>
</run>
<run underlined="none" subsuperscript="none" fontSize="800" fontFace="Times New Roman" fontFamily="roman" fontPitch="variable" spacing="2" foreColor="0c0c0c"><wd l="7298" t="2506" r="7646" b="2626">Parts</wd>
</run>
</ln>
</para>
<para l="6444" t="2736" r="7258" b="2868" alignment="justified" li="2088" spaceBefore="38" lsp="exactly" lspExact="207" language="en">
<ln l="6444" t="2736" r="7258" b="2868" baseLine="2866" underlined="none" subsuperscript="none" fontSize="900" fontFace="Times New Roman" fontFamily="roman" fontPitch="variable" spacing="0" foreColor="0c0c0c">
<wd l="6444" t="2736" r="6936" b="2868">xxxxxx</wd>
<space/>
<wd l="6982" t="2741" r="7258" b="2868">Hse</wd>
</ln>
</para>
<para l="6449" t="2976" r="7219" b="3108" alignment="justified" li="2088" spaceBefore="35" lsp="exactly" lspExact="207" language="en">
<ln l="6449" t="2976" r="7219" b="3108" baseLine="3108" underlined="none" subsuperscript="none" fontSize="900" fontFace="Times New Roman" fontFamily="roman" fontPitch="variable" spacing="0" foreColor="0c0c0c">
<wd l="6449" t="2976" r="6965" b="3108">Oxxxx</wd>
<space/>
<wd l="7010" t="2976" r="7219" b="3108">Rd</wd>
</ln>
</para>
<para l="6454" t="3218" r="8198" b="3348" alignment="justified" li="2088" spaceBefore="31" lsp="exactly" lspExact="207" language="en">
<ln l="6454" t="3218" r="8198" b="3348" baseLine="3346">
<run underlined="none" subsuperscript="none" fontSize="900" fontFace="Times New Roman" fontFamily="roman" fontPitch="variable" spacing="1" foreColor="0c0c0c"><wd l="6454" t="3218" r="6739" b="3348">SL9</wd>
<space/>
<wd l="6794" t="3218" r="7745" b="3348">7Bxxxx</wd>
<space/>
</run>
<run underlined="none" subsuperscript="none" fontSize="800" fontFace="Times New Roman" fontFamily="roman" fontPitch="variable" spacing="1" foreColor="0c0c0c"><wd l="7805" t="3223" r="8198" b="3346">Cross</wd>
</run>
</ln>
</para>
<para l="6449" t="3458" r="7810" b="3588" alignment="justified" li="2088" spaceBefore="33" spaceAfter="125" lsp="exactly" lspExact="207" language="en">
<ln l="6449" t="3458" r="7810" b="3588" baseLine="3586" underlined="none" subsuperscript="none" fontSize="900" fontFace="Times New Roman" fontFamily="roman" fontPitch="variable" spacing="0" foreColor="0c0c0c">
<wd l="6449" t="3458" r="7042" b="3588">GREAT</wd>
<space/>
<wd l="7092" t="3463" r="7810" b="3586">BRITAIN</wd>
</ln>
</para>
</dd>
<dd l="139" t="266" r="689" b="962">
<picture l="139" t="413" r="689" b="962" alignment="left" spaceBefore="147">
</picture>
</dd>
<dd l="139" t="2279" r="2508" b="3762">
<para l="149" t="2302" r="2105" b="2424" alignment="justified" lsp="exactly" lspExact="185" language="en">
<ln l="149" t="2302" r="2105" b="2424" baseLine="2422" bold="true" underlined="none" subsuperscript="none" fontSize="800" fontFace="Times New Roman" fontFamily="roman" fontPitch="variable" spacing="16" foreColor="0c0c0c">
<wd l="149" t="2302" r="518" b="2422">VAT</wd>
<space/>
<wd l="574" t="2304" r="833" b="2424">No:</wd>
<space/>
<wd l="1054" t="2302" r="2105" b="2424">GB530000000</wd>
</ln>
</para>
```

Comment: Can you show an example of the input XML?  Does it make use of any namespaces?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<document xmlns="http://www.scansoft.com/omnipage/xml/ssdoc-schema3.xsd"
```

This declaration puts all the un-prefixed element names in the document into a namespace, so you need to assign a prefix to that namespace in the XSLT and then use the prefix in your XPath expressions:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
         xmlns:ss="http://www.scansoft.com/omnipage/xml/ssdoc-schema3.xsd">

  <!-- ... -->
  <td><xsl:value-of select="/ss:document/ss:page/ss:body/ss:dd[1]/ss:dd[1]/ss:dd/ss:table/ss:cell[1]/ss:para[1]/ss:ln[1]/ss:wd[3]" /></td>
```

This is because unprefixed node names in an XPath 1.0 expression always refer to nodes that are *not* in a namespace.

Unrelated to this, I would personally avoid using an XPath expression that is so heavily tied to the precise layout of the XML document in terms of "the third wd of the first ln of...." - you could instead use something like

```
<xsl:value-of select="//ss:wd[preceding-sibling::ss:wd[2] = 'VAT']
                             [preceding-sibling::ss:wd[1] = 'No:']" />
```

to specifically target a `wd` whose two preceding `wd`s are "VAT" and "No:", wherever it happens to occur.

Comment: "This declaration puts all the un-prefixed element names in the document into a namespace, so you need to assign a prefix to that namespace in the XSLT and then use the prefix in your XPath expressions"

How can I change it so that I do not need to do this?

Comment: @Dan you can't within the XSLT (1.0), you'd have to edit the input XML file to remove the namespace declaration.  If you had access to XSLT 2.0 then you could use `xpath-default-namespace` but that is not available in 1.0 (given your use of `<?xml-stylesheet` I presume you're using a browser to do the transformation, and browsers only support 1.0).

Comment: I do have the ability to edit the input XML file. Is this as simple as adding an extra line at the start?

Comment: @Dan it should be sufficient to replace the whole starting `<document xmlns="...." xmlns:xsi="...">` tag with just `<document>`.

Comment: Thanks, is there any disadvantage to doing this to the document?