# Group words by every line via XSL

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm working with an OCR document that's been converted into XML. This means that the words on the page are quite oddly arranged (path-wise) in the document.

In the XML document, words are laid out like this   /document/...../ln/wd
What I'd like my XSLT document to do is print the words in each line on their own output line (i.e. detect the words in the XML document and 'preserve' their formatting).

What I have so far is this, which just prints every wd in the document, regardless of formatting/location.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
         xmlns:ss="http://www.scansoft.com/omnipage/xml/ssdoc-schema3.xsd">
<xsl:template match="/">
  <html>
    <body>
        <xsl:value-of select="/document::descendant::wd"/>
    </body>
  </html>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: Is this the same format as in [your previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20949113/printing-a-value-using-xslt-xpath) with alternating `wd` and `space` elements in each `ln`?

Comment: @IanRoberts It is indeed

Comment: And do you want the output to be HTML (using `p` or `br` tags to break the lines) or plain text?

Comment: Plain text would be great, with comma delimiters

Comment: `/document::descendant::wd` is not valid XPath. I'm pretty sure your XSLT processor tells you that.

Comment: @Tomalak I'm using Dreamweaver. It may not be configured properly - should it tell me? Or is there a better, free XML editor?

Comment: It's not about the editor you use. For all I'm concerned you could be using Notepad. ;) The XPath expression *itself* is invalid. It won't even compile.

Comment: @Tomalak I think I may be missing something here - I'm just saving it as XSLT.xsl and calling it from within the XML file :s

Comment: Okay. `/document::descendant::wd` is a *syntax error*. This expression can never work. You mean `/document/descendant::wd`.

Comment: @Tomalak It's odd, when I do that and open the XML file, I get nothing come up at all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20949113/printing-a-value-using-xslt-xpath), the format you're working with is (simplified)

```
<document xmlns="http://www.scansoft.com/omnipage/xml/ssdoc-schema3.xsd">
  <!-- other intervening elements -->
  <ln>
    <wd>First</wd>
    <space/>
    <wd>line</wd>
  </ln>
  <ln>
    <wd>Second</wd>
    <space/>
    <wd>line</wd>
  </ln>
  <ln>
    <run>
      <wd>Word</wd>
      <tab />
    </run>
    <run>
      <wd>another</wd>
      <space/>
    </run>
  </ln>
</document>
```

So you can approach this quite nicely using template matching

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
         xmlns:ss="http://www.scansoft.com/omnipage/xml/ssdoc-schema3.xsd">
  <xsl:output method="text" />

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="//ss:ln" />
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- for a ln, process the descendant words and spaces in document order -->
  <xsl:template match="ss:ln">
    <xsl:apply-templates select=".//ss:wd | .//ss:space | .//ss:tab" />
    <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text><!-- and add a newline character to the end -->
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- replace <space/> with a single space character -->
  <xsl:template match="ss:space">
    <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- replace <tab/> with a single tab character -->
  <xsl:template match="ss:tab">
    <xsl:text>&#09;</xsl:text>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- wd elements use the default built in template rule that will
       just output their contained text -->
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

If you have any `wd` elements that contain leading or trailing whitespace then you might want to add an explicit template to handle those:

```
<xsl:template match="ss:wd">
  <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space()" />
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Thankyou for this perfect answer! One extra thing; how could this be configured if not all of the text were not uniform?
For example, I have a fair amount of text in 
/ln/run/wd and using <tab /> for spacing. I thought I could rework whatever answer I got to account for this, but I don't think that's easy with template matching

Comment: @Dan I've expanded my example to handle tabs too.

Answer (score 0):

> What I'd like my XSLT document to do is print the words in each line
>   on their own output line (i.e. detect the words in the XML document
>   and 'preserve' their formatting).

Perhaps you could this simply by:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:ss="http://www.scansoft.com/omnipage/xml/ssdoc-schema3.xsd">

<xsl:output method="text" encoding="utf-8" />

<xsl:template match="/">
<xsl:for-each select="descendant::ss:ln">
    <xsl:for-each select="descendant::ss:wd">
        <xsl:value-of select="." />
        <xsl:if test="position()!=last()">
            <xsl:text>, </xsl:text>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each> 
    <xsl:if test="position()!=last()">
        <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:for-each> 
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Not sure what "'preserve' their formatting" means - esp. when the output is plain text.